# Does anybody know if CentOS have official support for OVAL definitions?

Tags: cve, centos

I saw it [here](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=59048) that CentOS have no official support for OVAL security definitions(patch, vulnerabilities).

Based on what I observe at [oval.mitre.org](http://oval.mitre.org/rep-data/5.10/org.mitre.oval/v/index.html), it looks like they don't even have a vulnerability definition for CentOS 7.x.

[image: it stops at CentOS6]

Is this true? If so, do we have other options for security management on CentOS systems?

Comment: The note at the top of the page at your link says that the site you are using is not current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVAL has transitioned to the Center for Internet Security (CIS) https://oval.cisecurity.org/ . The MITRE OVAL website is in "Archive" status.

Have a look here https://oval.cisecurity.org/repository/download , there you'll find CentOS 7

Comment: Its an empty "shell" OVAL and has nothing inside it